C strlen() returns the wrong String length (character count) when using umlauts
I'm working on a C program, which takes an input in form of a parameter and then needs the length of the string to continue its work.
Unfortunately I'm facing a massive issue in form of a wrong character count for the string while using strlen() on an input, which contains umlauts because that function counts umlauts as two characters!
Example:
strlen("abc"); //-> 3
strlen("äbc"); //-> 4
strlen("äöü"); //-> 6

Is there a way to have the actual character count even when using umlauts? I do NOT need the string length in bytes.

You might like the "UTF-8 Manifesto", especially section 8.

How are the non-ASCII characters encoded? UTF8? UTF16? UTF32? Something else?

Check out the wchar.h header: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide

strlen works with single-byte characters. To decode UFT8 multibyte ones you need to write your own function (for educational purposes)



Unicode Range
Binary Pattern
Bytes Used




U+0000 - U+007F
0xxxxxxx
1 byte


U+0080 - U+07FF
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
2 bytes


U+0800 - U+FFFF
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
3 bytes


U+10000 - U+10FFFF
11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
4 bytes






Character
Unicode
UTF-8 Encoding
Bytes




A
U+0041
[0] [1000001]
1 byte


€ (Euro Sign)
U+20AC
[1110] [0010] [10] [000010] [10] [101100]
3 bytes


 (Grinning Face)
U+1F600
[11110] [000] [10] [011111] [10] [100110] [10] [000000]
4 bytes



size_t utf8_strlen(const char *s) {
    size_t length = 0;

    if(s)
    {
        while (*s) 
        {
            unsigned char c = (unsigned char)*s;

            if ((c & 0x80) == 0x00) 
            {
                // 1-byte character: 0xxxxxxx
                s++;
            } else if ((c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) 
            {
                // 2-byte character: 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
                s += 2;
            } else if ((c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) 
            {
                // 3-byte character: 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
                s += 3;
            } else if ((c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) 
            {
                // 4-byte character: 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
                s += 4;
            } else 
            {
                // Invalid UTF-8 character, skip 1 byte
                s++;
            }

            length++;
        }
    }
    return length;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%zu\n", utf8_strlen("abc")); 
    printf("%zu\n", utf8_strlen("äbc")); 
    printf("%zu\n", utf8_strlen("äöü")); 
}

https://godbolt.org/z/xG89TMY9v

UV for well formed UTF-8 strings.  Concerning ill-formed UTF8 strings:  code nicely detects a leading Invalid UTF-8 character, yet does not insure proper UTF-8 characters exist in the 2,3,4 byte characters (or even a null).  It also fails to detect some other invalid sequences. alternative offers a simpler incomplete approach.

@chux it is not full solution - just an example to show what the problem was in his original code :)

strlen() does not return number of characters, but number of bytes (char) of the string.
Non-ascii characters such that "äöü" are 2 bytes long.
It exists wchar_t type (C++) for unicode strings.
